# can I trust node.js? safety/stability issues

Tags: node.js

Dont get me wrong people, let me clarify.

I would like to ask if I can trust node.js.  I know its an amazing tool. But its a really young platform, to be honest. Should I start playing around with it (production, not just experimental use), or should I wait till it "grows up"? 
Does it work fine on Windows? Because at the beginig it was not supported. Are there any stress tests that actually prove that its safe and can be trusted?

It demands to write a lot of code by hand, stuff that in other platforms are done by just one line of code. I know you are gonna say to me "that depends on your experience" . I agree, but does it worth "learning" node? What if its developing stops? Again, I'm only asking because its pretty young.

What of node's add-ons and modules are to be trusted about their safety/stability? There are so many out there.

Is it stable? And finally, what about node's interoperability? Does it work on every platform/browser? What about smartphones and mobile devices?

Again, dont get me wrong, I am not critisizing. I am just concerned because its pretty new, everybody is excited and I haven't see any cons, or safety/stability issues around.

Thanks

Comment: So wrong question for SO: you are asking for opinions, you are asking 10+ vague question in one (instead of one concrete), you are asking if someone else can make decision how *you* should behave...

Comment: This isn't really the [sort of question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) SO is intended for. Still: 1) "[*After 0.12, the next major stable release will be 1.0.*](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/03/11/node-v0-10-0-stable/)" 2) Node is intentionally low-level. For those "*one line of code*" scenarios, find a [library you like](https://npmjs.org/). 3) It works fine on Windows, albeit with a [bit more setup required](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) for native addons. 4) It's stability is described [per module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_modules).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hi there. I am asking about safety, security, stability and stress tests. People can say their opinion, anyway, but providing some links for stability , those are facts. I'm not asking for people to decide how I should behave. I'm going to use it experimentally, anyway.OK, you know what? Maybe I should edit the question

Comment: @Paul So, you point? Is there an analogy?

Comment: @slevin I guess the point is these kinds of questions (should I use it? is it ready? is it safe?) apply to almost anything. They tend to be incomplete questions too (use it for what? ready for what? safe for what?).

Comment: @Paul Used in production without problems or major bugs. Maybe, for example, you knew something I do not, perhaps a safety issue, and you could inform me. Anyway, maybe because english is not my native language I did not make the question clear enough. I edit it already 2 times, hope its closer to SO standards now

Comment: @slevin `Used in production without problems` I cannot name a single platform that matches that criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why would anyone choose to use node.js to do backend: the statically typed code is easier to maintain and Javascript is not the best (a good?) language.
That said, there are situations, where it makes a lot of sense to have the same code running in the browser and in the back end.  When you run into one of these, you will know. And then Node works just fine.  We've had it in production for months exposing its functionality as an internal web service to our back end application and haven't had any problems with it.

Comment: Well, you know, for bigger applications there are solutions like TypeScript.

Comment: Isomorphic (universal) code is not the only sell point of Node.

Comment: Oh please do tell what are the other sell points of Node.